# SEO effect for Blocking entire site for a country and allowing only one page

Tags: seo, google, redirects, cloudflare

Need your valuable guidance.

Suppose via Cloudflare if we add a redirect rule for a specific country. Where if any traffic comes from that country, it will get redirected to a special subfolder dedicated only to that country like the one below:

`example.com/allowed`

This way, visitors from that country can access only that particular page instead of the whole site.

Will this practice be good for SEO, as in Google search? I want Google to show only the example.com/allowed page in search results, for that specific country.

It may sound complex. But not sure will that be a good idea. Please help.

**Note**: It will have different content for that specific country, a dedicated subfolder, and a page only for that country.

The goal is, not fully block a country from viewing the whole site, only allowing a page to view for that specific country without the negative effect of SEO. So in this case that country's search results will show only that page, not the entire site because it is not allowed to view.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure that you treat the google crawlers exactly the same as you do any other traffic to your website from other countries. So those redirect rules should apply to the GoogleBots like they apply to regular traffic. This way, Google knows what pages are allowed in those countries and can adjust its search results accordingly.

More details here:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/locale-adaptive-pages